# Prove that each connected component is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, connectedness

Good evening, I'm doing exercise II.4.6 in textbook *Analysis I* by Amann.

> [image]
>
> Here $X$ is a metric space.

Could you please verify if my attempt contains logical mistakes/gaps! Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:**

(a)

For $x \in X$. Let $M_x = \{Y \in \mathcal P(X) \mid Y \, \text{is connected} \wedge x \in Y \}$. Then $\{x\} \in M_x$. We have $X =\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\} \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in X} K(x) \subseteq X$, so $X = \bigcup_{x \in X} K(x)$.

Assume that $K(x) \cap K(y)$ is nonempty. Then $K(x) \cup K(y)$ is connected. So $M_y \ni (K(x) \cup K(y)) \in M_x$ and hence $(K(x) \cup K(y)) \subseteq K(x)$ and $(K(x) \cup K(y)) \subseteq K(y)$. Then $K(x) = K(y)$.

As such, $\{K(x) \mid x \in X\}$ is a partition of $X$.

(b)

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $K(a)$ such that $x_n \to b \in X$. Then $K(x_n) =K(a)$ for all $n$. There exists $x_N \in \mathbb B(b,1)$. On the other hand, $\mathbb B(b,1)$ is connected. So $\mathbb B(b,1) \in M_{x_N}$ and hence $\mathbb B(b,1) \subseteq K(x_N) = K(a)$. As such, $b \in K(a)$. Hence $K(a)$ is closed.

**Update:** Here is my fixed proof of (b):

For $x \in K(a)$, $x \in \overline{K(a)}$. Because $K(a)$ is connected, $\overline{K(a)}$ is connected. So $\overline{K(a)} \in M_a$ and hence $\overline{K(a)} \subseteq K(a) \subseteq \overline{K(a)}$. As such, $K(a) = \overline{K(a)}$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Balls may not be connected in a generic metric space. For instance, the only connected subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are the points (which have empty interior).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing our my wrong understanding @Gae.S. :(

Comment: You should rather try to prove that, if $A$ is connected and $A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline A$, then $B$ is connected. This is true in all topological spaces.

Comment: I have just fixed it @Gae.S. Please have a check on my fix!

Comment: I you can take for granted what I said, then yes, I assume that's as good as any way to fill in the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this fact: the closure of a connected set is connected. Here is the proof:  if $\overline A=C\cup D$ for some non-empty sets $C,D$ open in $\overline A$.  Since $A$ is connected, we may assume without loss of generality, that $A\subseteq C$. Then, $\overline A\subseteq \overline C.$ But $\overline C\cap D=\emptyset$ (why?) and so $\overline A\cap D=\emptyset$. Thus, we have shown that $D$ is empty, which is a contradiction.

Now, let $C$ be a component of $x$. Then, $x\in \overline C$, which is connected, so by definition of component, $\overline C\subseteq C$. That is, $\overline C=C$, so $C$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you so much for tackling many of my questions ^o^

Comment: You're welcome!